# mysql join table query probleme

Tags: mysql

I have those table

```
create table patient(
PatientId integer not null,
FirstName varchar(15) not null,
LastName  varchar(15) not null,
Address varchar(40) not null,
DateOfBirth date not null,
Gender varchar(1) not null,
Height varchar(10),
Weight varchar(10),
Phone varchar(20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(PatientId) 
);

create table room(
RoomNo integer  not null,
Type varchar(25) not null,
NumberOfBeds numeric(1) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(RoomNo)
);



create table diagnostic(
   DiagnosticId integer not null,
   Description varchar(25) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(DiagnosticId)
   );

   create table patientRoom(
   PatientId integer not null,
   RoomNo integer not null,
   DateStart date not null,
   DateEnd date not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(PatientId, RoomNo, DateStart),
   FOREIGN KEY(PatientId) REFERENCES patient(PatientId),
   FOREIGN KEY(RoomNo) REFERENCES room(RoomNo)
   );

   create table patientDiagnostic(
   PatientId integer not null,
   DiagnosticId integer not null,
   Date date not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(PatientId,DiagnosticId),
   FOREIGN KEY(PatientId) REFERENCES patient(PatientId),
   FOREIGN KEY(DiagnosticId) REFERENCES diagnostic(DiagnosticId)
   );
```

And I am trying to join the table so I got the FirstName LastName of the patient, with his 
diagnostic, RoomNo with the date he came and the date he left

I tried this

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName,
d.Description,
pr.RoomNo, pr.DateStart, pr.DateEnd
from patient p, patientRoom pr, diagnostic d, patientDiagnostic pd
where p.PatientId = pd.PatientId
and 
pd.PatientId = pr.PatientId
and
pd.DiagnosticId = d.DiagnosticId;
```

but I get 361 rows instead of 245 rows 
I think the mistake is in :

```
where p.PatientId = pd.PatientId
and
pd.PatientId = pr.PatiendId.
```

but I dont know how to fix it. 
Like some Patient got 3 different diagnostic at different date 
but those are getting I got 9 rows instead of 3 rows

edit : I will try to explain better what is happening , 
so Example
I have this row
Simon Vermette got an heart attack in room 2 on 2014-03-04 until 2014-03-07 , 
and asthma in room 4 on 2014-06-04 until 2014-06-08

It will have a row
Simon Vermette hearth attack 2014-03-04 2014-03-07
Simon Vermette Asthma        2014-03-04 2014-03-07

Simon Vermette hearth attack 2014-06-04 2014-06-08
Simon Vermette asthma        2014-06-04 2014-06-08

Comment: So I tried the same query I had before but I wrote select distinct instead and I still have the same table

Comment: Give small example values for all tables, your output, and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, d.Description, pr.RoomNo, pr.DateStart, pr.DateEnd
 FROM patient p
 LEFT JOIN patientroom pr ON ( pr.PatientId = p.PatientId )
 LEFT JOIN patientdiagnostic pd ON ( pd.PatientId = p.PatientId )
 LEFT JOIN diagnostic d ON ( d.DiagnosticId = pd.DiagnosticId )
 GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, d.Description
```

Comment: okok it is closer , I have now 245 rows like I am supposed to , but it is still giving the same date and room to every patient who have more than one diagnostic. anyways thank you, I'll go to bed. I am gonna check that tomorrow. thank you

Comment: I got your point...i modified the query now try this

SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, d.Description, pr.RoomNo, pr.DateStart, pr.DateEnd
 FROM patient p
 LEFT JOIN patientroom pr ON ( pr.PatientId = p.PatientId )
 LEFT JOIN patientdiagnostic pd ON ( pd.PatientId = p.PatientId )
 RIGHT JOIN diagnostic d ON ( d.DiagnosticId = pd.DiagnosticId )
 AND pd.Date=pr.DateStart
 GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, d.Description

Comment: okok cool it is working but except it is removing 2 rows , I am going to check which row are removed to see what is the problem , thank you

Comment: Ok the problem were in my tables. thank you it is working fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Without DISTINCT the WHERE filters from all possible combinations of a row from each FROM table. Using DISTINCT removes duplicates after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName,
d.Description,
pr.RoomNo, pr.DateStart, pr.DateEnd
from patient p LEFT JOIN  patientRoom pr ON (pr.PatientId = p.PatientId)
LEFT JOIN patientDiagnostic pd ON  (pd.PatientId = p.PatientId)
LEFT JOIN  diagnostic d ON (d.DiagnosticId = pd.DiagnosticId)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this query

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName,
d.Description,
pr.RoomNo, pr.DateStart, pr.DateEnd
from patient p, patientRoom pr, diagnostic d, patientDiagnostic pd
where p.PatientId = pd.PatientId
and 
p.PatientId = pr.PatientId
and
pd.DiagnosticId = d.DiagnosticId;
```